# Equivalent for pop on strings

Tags: python, string, string-parsing

Given a very large string. I would like to process parts of the string in a loop like this:

```
large_string = "foobar..."
while large_string:
    process(large_string.pop(200))
```

What is a nice and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly do you want? The first 200 characters? The 200th character? Something else?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Isn't the while loop clearly showing that I want to process all characters of the string?

Comment: It looks like you want to remove and process the 200th character of large_string until pop throws "IndexError: pop index out of range"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can wrap the string in a `StringIO` or `BytesIO` and pretend it's a file. That should be pretty fast.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
# or, in Py3/Py2.6+:
#from io import BytesIO, StringIO

s = StringIO(large_string)
while True:
    chunk = s.read(200)
    if len(chunk) > 0:
        process(chunk)
    if len(chunk) < 200:
        break
```

Comment: If he want to consume the string from the end this does not work.

Comment: @ms4py fortunately the order of the chunks does not matter at all for my task

Comment: @ms4py: true. In that case, I'd slice the string up into a list and iterate over it in reverse: `[large_string[i:i+200] for i in xrange(0, len(large_string), 200)]`

Comment: @larsmans: Or, you could use the buffer's seek method to read the last _n_ bytes: `s.seek(-200, 2); chunk = s.read()`...

Comment: You don't need Py3 for `io.StringIO` - it exists from 2.6.

Comment: One of the benefits of `pop` is that it discards the elements it returns, releasing the memory they occupied. `StringIO` does not discard the parts of the string that were already read. Is there a way to get this aspect of the `pop` functionality for strings?

Comment: @Joe: from what I know of CPython internals, I don't think any solution will partially deallocate the string and retain linear time complexity for taking slices off it.

Answer (score 13):

you can convert the string to a list. `list(string)` and pop it, or you could iterate in chunks slicing the list `[]` or you can slice the string as is and iterate in chunks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [slicing](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
large_string = "foobar..."
while large_string:
    process(large_string[-200:])
    large_string = large_string[:-200]
```

Comment: This is pretty wasteful. Not only because it does the slicing twice, but because it uses an O(n²) time algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on dm03514's answer, you can do something like this:

```
output = ""
ex = "hello"
exList = list(ex)
exList.pop(2)
for letter in exList:
    output += letter

print output # Prints 'helo'
```